# NSMutableParagraphStyle shifting text down slightly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I have a `UILabel` which uses an `NSAttributedString` to display `"GAME OVER"`. I have positioned the text in IB and it displays in the correct place. My problem is that I want the text centred onscreen but when I setup a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` my text shifts down a few pixels.

[image]

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *pStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[pStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

NSDictionary *dict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : displayColor,
                                  NSFontAttributeName : displayFont,
                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pStyle};
```

If I leave out `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` then the text is positioned correctly, add it in and it centers correctly but shifts down by 5-6pixels. Does anyone know what is causing this, there is obviously some default that I am not setting that is causing the shift.